# cannot decrypt String from text file

Tags: java, file, encryption, byte, aes

In my journey to mastering Java, I started doing some AES encryption and decryption, but ran into some problems. I can encrypt and decrypt just fine using my 2 methods below.

```
public static byte[] encryptString(String datatoEncrypt, String myKey, Cipher cipher)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] text = datatoEncrypt.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
        byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(myKey);
        SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length, "AES"); 
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, originalKey);
        byte[] textEncrpted = cipher.doFinal(text);
        
        return textEncrpted;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and the decrypt method

```
public static String decryptString(byte[] datatoDecrypt, String myKey, Cipher cipher)
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Key " + myKey);
        byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(myKey);
        SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length, "AES"); 
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, originalKey);
        byte[] textDecrpted = cipher.doFinal(datatoDecrypt);
        String result = new String(textDecrpted, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        
        return result;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

My problem is when I encrypt, I am saving the encrypted file to a text file, and now I am trying to decrypt that text file, but it won't decrypt.

```
public static void task1()
{
    System.out.println("Key in file path name: ");        
    String filename = keyboard.nextLine();
    
    try
    {
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        
        String message = readFile(filename);
        String key = generateKey();
        Cipher chipher;
        chipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        System.out.println("Key is " +key);
        byte[] encryptedData = encryptString(message, key, chipher);
        String encryptedString = new String(encryptedData);
        System.out.println("Encrypted data is: " + encryptedString);
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("ciphertext.txt");
        writer.println(encryptedString);
        writer.close();
        
        byte[] tryagain;
        System.out.println("enter File name");
        String filename1 = keyboard.nextLine();
        
        tryagain = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filename1));
        
        System.out.println("Enter Key");
        String keyString = keyboard.nextLine();
        String decrypted = decryptString(tryagain,keyString,chipher);
        System.out.println("Decrypted data: "  + decrypted);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error " );
    }
}
```

It keeps giving me back null, I believe the problem is the text file as when not using text files it runs just fine. Below is some code the operated normally when not using text files.

```
String text = "Santosisverycool";
String key = generateKey();
Cipher chipher;
chipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
System.out.println("Key is " +key);
byte[] encryptedData = encryptString(text, key, chipher);
String encryptedString = new String(encryptedData);
System.out.println("Encrypted data is: " + encryptedString);

String decrypted = decryptString(encryptedData,key,chipher);
System.out.println("decrypted: " +decrypted);
```

Does anyone have any solutions? I have been stuck on this problem for at least a week and haven't gotten any closer to solving it.

Comment: So use binary file

Comment: if you debug the decrypted string, you'll notice it ends with an additional `\n` or `\r\n`, depending you're on linux or windows...so, it's just not the same message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>writer.println(encryptedString);</s>

`println` prints the string, plus a newline after the string. You don't want a new line, just the string. Replace it with:

```
writer.print(encryptedString);
```

As pointed out in the comments, the byte array will most likely contain unprintable characters, making the resulting data corrupt. Instead:

just skip the string conversion and write the byte array directly to a file with `FileOutputStream`:

```
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("ciphertext.txt")) {
    fos.write(encryptedData);
}
```

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk you're absolutely correct, fixed. For some reason I imagined a base64 conversion in there somewhere, but op is indeed just creating a string from the byte array.